# Automatic Sequential number for grouped items in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sequential

I have two lists, one that store a person main Info and the other that Dynamically store the details. but I need a list to mix both of them and add a sequential number to the output list.

E.G

MAIN

```
ID --- NAME   ---  AGE
 1 --- Jack   ---   23
 2 --- Robert ---   30
 3 --- Lee    ---   15
```

DETAILS

```
ID -- MAINLinK -- Details
1  --    1     --  Tall         <= Jack
2  --    1     --  Thin         <= Jack
3  --    1     --  Blonde       <= Jack
4  --    2     --  Fat          <= Robert
5  --    3     --  Chinesse     <= Lee  
6  --    3     --  skinny       <= Lee
```

Required List:

```
Id(MAIN) -- SequentialNUM  -- Name(MAIN)
1        --       1        --  Jack   
1        --       2        --  Jack
1        --       3        --  Jack
2        --       1        --  Robert
3        --       1        --  Lee
3        --       2        --  Lee
```

the Sequential Number is the one I really need...

NOTE: this is just a simple example to get what I really need and I can't find the way to just put in a single Linq statement to do this this without adding loops and create more objects.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you move this grouping to SQL? The T-SQL `ROW_NUMBER()` function is perfect for this..

Comment: no really, this is something that I need to get it solved in linq, I now how to solve this in SQL  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = MainList.Join(DetailsList, x=>x.ID, x=>x.MAINLink,(x,y)=> new {x,y})
                   .GroupBy(a=>a.x.ID)
                   .Select(g=>g.Select((k,i)=>new {k,i}))
                   .SelectMany(a=>a)
                   .Select((a)=> new {
                                     Main = a.k.x,
                                     SequentialNUM = a.i + 1,
                                     Detail = a.k.y
                                   })
                   .OrderBy(x=>x.Main.Id);
```

Comment: That would return an error, I tried that way, but I could make it works by just setting it to list prior the select.  the only problem is that the index your adding is not per group and that's what i need, yours add a sequential number for the whole list.

Comment: dude, there's only one word I can tell you, RESPECT!
it worked just need to add a ToList() after the Groupby.